# Calculate difference between two row amount in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having a table with which calculates `balance`, where I have these columns in the table:

```
> describe tbl_credit_log

+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| visitor_id       | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| post_owner_id    | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| post_id          | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| balance          | double(50,6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| credits          | double(50,6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| debits           | double(50,6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| trans_id         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| trans_amount     | double(50,6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| earningtype      | varchar(15)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Where here is the few entries from which I want to do the calculations :

```
+---------+------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| id      | visitor_id | post_owner_id | post_id | advertisement_id | balance     | credits   | debits | created_at          |
+---------+------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| 4331666 |      11006 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 3639.624400 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-10 05:45:37 |
| 4364034 |       7206 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5139.607900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-10 11:02:52 |
| 4377238 |       4353 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5162.107900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-10 12:52:01 |
| 4485288 |       9664 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5184.607900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-11 08:58:19 |
| 4544185 |      11709 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5207.107900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-11 19:06:52 |
| 4550728 |      11970 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5229.607900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-11 20:39:36 |
| 4607317 |      12021 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5252.107900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-12 07:29:17 |
| 4629660 |      11926 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5274.607900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-12 09:18:56 |
| 4725299 |      12088 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5297.107900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-13 01:54:53 |
| 4725347 |      10253 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5319.607900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-13 08:29:46 |
| 4725357 |      12140 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5342.107900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-13 09:27:44 |
+---------+------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
```

here **`we have difference (more then 50) in amount on id number`4364034** which I want to find in whole database where user id will be `post_owner_id` as foreign key.

**I want to get all the `post_owner_id` who have difference in the amount and their `created_at`**.

So the expected results will be something like this

```
+---------+------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
    | id      | visitor_id | post_owner_id | post_id | advertisement_id | balance     | credits   | debits | created_at          |
    +---------+------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
    | 4364034 |       7206 |            11 |    NULL |             NULL | 5139.607900 | 22.500000 |   NULL | 2018-08-10 11:02:52 |
    +---------+------------+---------------+---------+------------------+-------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
```

here we will have multiple `post_owner_id`. I am showing one `post_owner_id` because this result is only of one post owner id. But I want to get different post owner id who have difference **`balance` is more then 50.**

I am not able to figure out how can I do this.  I want to compare prices on `group_by` post_owner_id and get the row where the difference amount is.

Comment: 'amount'? What is 'amount'? Anyway, the answer will be 11, because that's the only post_owner_id

Comment: no amount = `balance` @Strawberry

Comment: So, you're looking for the rows where the difference between consecutive balances is greater than 50?

Comment: Yes @Strawberry you got the point.

Comment: I think my explanation is a little less verbose than yours!

Comment: Yes actually :) You said it very simply. I think I am thinking this query as more complicated then it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,balance DECIMAL(12,6) NOT NULL
,created_at timestamp NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(4331666,3639.624400,'2018-08-10 05:45:37'),
(4364034,5139.607900,'2018-08-10 11:02:52'),
(4377238,5162.107900,'2018-08-10 12:52:01'),
(4485288,5184.607900,'2018-08-11 08:58:19'),
(4544185,5207.107900,'2018-08-11 19:06:52'),
(4550728,5229.607900,'2018-08-11 20:39:36'),
(4607317,5252.107900,'2018-08-12 07:29:17'),
(4629660,5274.607900,'2018-08-12 09:18:56'),
(4725299,5297.107900,'2018-08-13 01:54:53'),
(4725347,5319.607900,'2018-08-13 08:29:46'),
(4725357,5342.107900,'2018-08-13 09:27:44');
```

Option 1:

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.id) y_id 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.created_at > x.created_at 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
     ) a 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.id = a.y_id 
   AND b.balance > a.balance + 50;
+---------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
| id      | balance     | created_at          | y_id    |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
| 4331666 | 3639.624400 | 2018-08-10 05:45:37 | 4364034 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT id
     , balance
     , created_at
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , @i<balance-50 i
            , @i:=balance
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @i:=null) vars
        ORDER
           BY created_at
     ) n
 WHERE i = 1;

 +---------+-------------+---------------------+
 | id      | balance     | created_at          |
 +---------+-------------+---------------------+
 | 4364034 | 5139.607900 | 2018-08-10 11:02:52 |
 +---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

You can adapt either of the techniques above to return either row

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry I tried this query. But seems like there is no place where I can put the `post_owner_id` I tried to put in OPTION 2. But it resulted all the values of that user.

Comment: In option 1, you just add it to the subquery and the joining criteria. In option 2, you have to add it to the order by clause, and adapt the @i<balance to reset whenever the user changes.